# Create a dataframe looping a function's results

Tags: r

So this is a simplification of my problem.
I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("lucas","julio","jack","juan"),number=c(1,15,100,22))
```

And I have a function that creates new values for every name, like this:

```
var_number <- function(x) {
  example <- df %>%
    filter(name %in% unique(df$name)[x]) %>% 
    select(-name) %>%
    mutate(value1=number/2^5, value2=number^5)
  (example)
}

var_number(1)
 0.03125 1
```

Now I have two new values for every name and I would like to create a loop to save each result in a new dataframe.
I know how to solve this particular problem, but I need a general solution that allows me to save the results of all functions into a dataframe.
I'm looking for an automatic way to do something like this:

```
result<- bind_rows(var_number(1),var_number(2),var_number(3),var_number(4))
```

Since I would have to apply var_number around 1000 times and the lenght would change with every test i do.
There is anyway I can do something like this? I was thinking about doing it with "for", but I'm not really sure about how to do it, I have just started with R and I am a total newbie.

Answer (score 1):

This answers my problem:

```
library(tidyverse) # contains purrr library

#an arbitrary function that always outputs a dataframe
# with a consistent number of columns, in this case 3
myfunc <- function(x){
data.frame(a=x*2,
         b=x^2,
         c=log2(x))
}

# iterate over 1:10 as inputs to myfunc, and
# combine the results rowwise into a df 
purrr::map_dfr(1:10,
           ~myfunc(.))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to apply `var_number` function for each name, create a new dataframe for each and then combine all of them together?

Do it only once in the same dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>% 
         mutate(value1=number/2^5,value2=number^5) %>%
         select(-name)
```

If you want to do it only for specific `names`, you can `filter` them first before applying the above.

Comment: I know how to solve this particular problem, I made it easy to focus in the second part:

I need to create a data frame of n rows where row 1 is function(1), row 2 is function(2) and so on. The lenght of n is going to change everytime and i am not sure about how to do so. I was thinking about doing it with a loop, but i am not really sure about how to.  
Another way might be something like this:

```
result<- bind_rows(var_number(1),var_number(2)....,var_number(n))
```

There is any way to do that?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: @IvanCereghetti So basically you cannot change the `var_number` function and it always returns a dataframe? Looking at your answer I think you can also do `do.call(rbind, lapply(1:10, myfunc))` keeping it in base R.